# I want to get the contents of whatever is typed into the summernote rich text editor to send an email via gmail but idk how

Tags: sendmail

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css/editor.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtEditor").Editor();
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/editor.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>LineControl | v1.1.0</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="row"
                 style="border: 1px darkgrey solid; border-radius: 10px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="header">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="logout"> logout </a></li>
                            <li>${login_email.email}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="myclass">Compose</h2>

                    <form action="formSender" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>To:</label> 
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>CC:</label> 
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="cc">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Subject:</label> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="content">Content:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="txtEditor" name="content"></textarea> 
                        </div>
                        <c:if test="${not empty message}">      
                            <div style="margin: auto; width: 300px">
                                <span style="color: red"> ${message} </span>
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

at Servlet :

```
String content = request.getParameter("content");
```